# How to run a js function in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am able to run a jasmine test on a js file, but it does not seem that I can run any functions from within the testing framework.

Here is the JS file jasmine_test.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function hello(){
        console.log("yo")
    }

    hello()

});
```

here is the form_detail_spec.js

```
describe("tthe things", function(){
    it("testing the things", function(){
        var array = ["one"];
        //isOptionalEmailForm(array);
        //expect(isOptionalEmailForm(array)).toBe(true);
        hello()
        expect(1).toBe(1);

    }); 
});
```

When I run the spec file, I get the following error in the jasmine console:

```
ReferenceError: hello is not defined
```

the spec does not pass. If I remove hello() from the test, it works beautifully.

here is the specrunner.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.2.0</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/boot.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/validator_parameters.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <!-- <script src="src/Player.js"></script> -->
  <!--  <script src="src/Song.js"></script> -->
  <script src="../js/jasmine_test.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <!--    <script src="spec/SpecHelper.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="spec/PlayerSpec.js"></script> -->
  <script src="spec/form_details_spec.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `hello` is inside of another function. It isn't exposed to the outside world, so you aren't going to be able to test it directly. It's really nice to write your functions as modules, like CommonJS, AMD, or the new [ES6 modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html), then test those modules.

This is how you would write and get access to a module with CommonJS/NodeJS

```
// hello.js
module.exports = hello; // export your function as a module
function hello() {
  // code here
}

// test.js
var hello = require('./path/to/hello'); // you don't need to write the .js extension
// you can now call `hello()` in your test code here.
```

The less ideal, more traditional way would be to make your `hello` function accessible through something inevitably from the global scope. Think jQuery, where you can access it's functions from the `jQuery` or `$` global variable.

```
// your-file.js
var myLib = {
  hello: function() {
     // code
  }
}
```

Then include `your-file.js`, so that the `myLib` variable is available globally. Then you can access `hello` from there with `myLib.hello()`. Or you could just make `hello` a global variable/function, but that's REALLY bad.

Modules are now the best practice. Since NodeJs is based on CommonJS modules, I use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to bring CommonJS modules client-side, and test everything with [tape](https://github.com/substack/tape), which is also a CommonJS module.